# Import config files based on environment with Create React App

Tags: import, configuration, environment-variables, create-react-app

I have files I want to import based on environment. Currently I import it into the file like this

```
import { myConfig } from "../config/my-config";
```

however I would like to do it based on environment import the correct config file based on environment.

So ideally I would have (they could be json and not TS)

```
my-config-dev.ts
my-config-staging.ts
my-config-prod.ts
```

How can I use the correct import based on the environment?

The easiest way would be use normal env variables in CRA e.g REACT_APP_MY_API_KEY, but I have about 3 of these config files and for maintainability I would like them to be in their own ts or json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more info, see [Adding Custom Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

From your example, I don't see the reason you should create the config file for each environment. Putting the config as `REACT_APP_XX` environment variables in the `.env` file is enough.

project directory structure:

```bash
✗ tree -a -L 3 -I 'node_modules|public|.git' 
.
├── .env.development
├── .env.production
├── .env.staging
├── .gitignore
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── src
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── config
    │   ├── dev.js
    │   ├── index.js
    │   ├── prd.js
    │   └── staging.js
    ├── index.js
    ├── reportWebVitals.js
    └── setupTests.js

2 directories, 15 files
```

`.env.development`:

```
REACT_APP_ENV=dev
```

`.env.staging`:

```
REACT_APP_ENV=staging
```

`.env.production`:

```
REACT_APP_ENV=prd
```

`src/config/dev.js`:

```js
const config = {
  domain: 'http://example-dev.com'
}
export default config;
```

`src/config/staging.js`:

```js
const config = {
  domain: 'http://example-staging.com'
}
export default config;
```

`src/config/prd.js`:

```js
const config = {
  domain: 'http://example.com'
}
export default config;
```

`src/config/index.js`:

```js
import dev from './dev';
import staging from './staging';
import prd from './prd';

const config = { dev, staging, prd }[process.env.REACT_APP_ENV]

export { config }
```

`App.js`:

```js
import './App.css';
import { config } from './config';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>NODE_ENV: {process.env.NODE_ENV}</p>
      <p>domain: {config.domain}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

We can [Customizing Environment Variables for Arbitrary Build Environments](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#customizing-environment-variables-for-arbitrary-build-environments) using the `env-cmd` package.

npm scripts:

```bash
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging npm run build",
  "build:dev": "env-cmd -f .env.development npm run build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Run `npm run build:dev`, then `npx serve -s build`:

[image]

Run `npm run build:staging`, then `npx serve -s build`:

[image]

For production environment build, run `npm run build`.

[image]